# Primary X axis in MS chart control wont display max value?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, charts

I am using MS chart control .net 4 framework in Visual studio 2010 using Windows forms. I am having an issue with the scale of the primary x axis on a user input from a text box on a button click. I am also using both the primary and secondary y axes which work on a user input.

I have checked the settings for each axis and they all have the same settings. I don't see why both y axes work on the user input and the x does not. Please help.

The following is the code I am using:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Chart1.ChartAreas("Area1").AxisX.Minimum = Val(XPrimeMin.Text)
    Chart1.ChartAreas("Area1").AxisX.Maximum = Val(XPrimeMax.Text)
    Chart1.ChartAreas("Area1").AxisX.Interval = Val(XPrimeInterval.Text)
    Chart1.ChartAreas("Area1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = Val(XPrimeInterval.Text)

    Chart1.ChartAreas("Area1").AxisY.Minimum = Val(YPrimeMin.Text)
    Chart1.ChartAreas("Area1").AxisY.Maximum = Val(YPrimeMax.Text)
    Chart1.ChartAreas("Area1").AxisY.Interval = Val(YPrimeInterval.Text)
    Chart1.ChartAreas("Area1").AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = Val(YPrimeInterval.Text)

    Chart1.ChartAreas("Area1").AxisY2.Minimum = Val(YSecMin.Text)
    Chart1.ChartAreas("Area1").AxisY2.Maximum = Val(YSecMax.Text)
    Chart1.ChartAreas("Area1").AxisY2.Interval = Val(YSecInterval.Text)
    Chart1.ChartAreas("Area1").AxisY2.LabelStyle.Interval = Val(YSecInterval.Text)

End Sub
```

This is a screen shot of what I get while on auto-scale:

[image]

This is after I set the Axes by user input:

[image]

Comment: If you set `Val(XPrimeMin.Text)` to a `double` and print it out, what do you get? (same for maximum and interval)?

Comment: they each indicated that they were a double as needed

Comment: I have found that it is an error with `LabelStyle.Interval` Again it works in the other axes, just not the x

Comment: Let me try to reproduce the problem then.  What is the exact error that you get with `LabelStyle.Interval`?

Comment: I am not getting any kind of error code or warnings. The problem is that even though the number is being assigned the axis stays at .69 unless i set the maximum number below that in which I don't see any values on the axis at all even though grid interval does change.

Comment: Do you set the Interval to a default value initially?  I'm not fully understanding what you mean by the axis stays at .69

Comment: Is it possible to put up a screencap, before and after you click the button.  I'm able to reproduce your code, but everything scales okay for me (but I don't know if we're using the same type of plot)

Comment: Initially it is set to Auto as the default. When I push the auto-scale button as in the screen shot it goes back to displaying properly again as in the first screen shot

Comment: I hate to keep throwing suggestions at you, but what happens if you try turning Auto off temporarily, or set the x-axis parameters after you've set the y-axis ones?  I wonder if it's trying to find a range over which the y-axis values are well represented.

Comment: Neither of the suggestions worked either.

Comment: Okay, I think I've expended all my options. Let it brew for a bit and see if there are any other responses.  If I think of anything, I'll post back.

Comment: I have found that the axis is using the x values of the series for the label points on the axis. Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: Try setting the `IsLabelAutoFit` property of `AxisX` to false

Comment: I already had that set to false but I managed to get it working by converting the value I was taking from the array to a double value before adding it to the series data point. The data was originally a string from a ini file. Everything seems to be working correctly now.

Comment: Great that it worked.  So you did need to use a `TryParse` method in the end for that?  If not, use that instead of a `Convert`.  Well, I hope the rest of the project runs more smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to convert the value I was taking from the array to a double value before adding it to the series data point.